# Loading widgets/gadgets dynamically on JQuery?

Tags: jquery, widget

I am planning to build a web app structured in widgets/gadgets.

The app will load various widgets/gadgets on demand. This way the user will create/configure the interface dynamically.

The closest framework I've seen to this approach is OpenSocial.

Dynamic loading can be done using jQuery-depends and RequireJs, but I'm looking for a more structured approach to load a gadget (script, css and templates).

Is there any library or framework in JQuery I can use for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See also Apache Wookie:

http://incubator.apache.org/wookie/

This provides a system for including W3C Widgets in websites using a REST API.

Also worth taking a look at Apache Rave:

http://rave.apache.org/

Which may provide the complete framework for the sort of application you're working on.